# How to automatically redirect from chrome custom tab back to app using current link?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

Scenario:

1. User open my android app, press a button - app opens chrome tab with certain link.
2. User browses to a specific page, the point is that link at address bar is changed
3. Now user wants to open this exact link back in application, so he presses three dots at upper right corner, chooses Open in Chrome. Two choices appears: 
   My app, Chrome.
4. User chooses My app
5. It is opened where Intent Receiver activity is parsing the desired link.
   [image]
   [image]

How I can make steps 3 and 4 automatic, so as soon as user gets to link at step 2, chrome Tab is instructed to do the following steps?

I am not sure why option "My app" appears after pressing "open in Chrome", but the fact is that it is.

The question may look like I ask you to do my homework, but I definitely couldn't find anything related to this specific task.

Comment: Did you end up working this out?